# How to use socket.io code in two client side JS files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

My code base uses two JavaScript files. One called production.js for all sitewide related Javascript and one based on the name of the page, in this case called messages.js

Most of my client side socket.io code is in messages.js.

However, I also want to push some notifications to the page header regardless of what page is being viewed so only that part of the socket.io code needs to be in production.js.

Without putting all of the socket.io code in production.js, how can I use socket.io in both files so that they both work without any conflict?

production.js is also loaded before messages.js.

Comment: Just move the connection part to the production file and it will be within the other file's scope.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the connection part in production.js.